# Parse .msg outlook file with flutter/dart

Tags: dart, winapi, outlook, msg, fileparsing

I need help running this python code in a windows flutter app

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(r"C:\test_msg.msg")
```

using the [win32](https://pub.dev/packages/win32) package, as I can't understand how to use it... I'm quite sure it's doable since [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/win32/latest/win32/DISPATCH_METHOD-constant.html) is available in the package and seems to be what is needed...

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way is to automate Outlook for that like the Python code does. Be aware, the code mentioned make sense only for Windows machines. The COM technology doesn't exists on other platforms.

Also you can find the [MSG file format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxmsg/b046868c-9fbf-41ae-9ffb-8de2bd4eec82) described in depth in MSDN. So, you may search for existing parsers over the internet or create your own.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Was looking for something like it.